# Issue with downloading webpage in java?

Tags: java, web

So I'm trying to download the text of an aspx webpage (Roblox) with java.  My code looks like this:

```
URL url;
InputStream is = null;
DataInputStream dis;
String line = "";
try {
    System.out.println("connecting");
    url = new URL("http://www.roblox.com");
    is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
    dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

    while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {}
}
```

And it works for www.roblox.com.  However, when I try to navigate to a different page - http://www.roblox.com/My/Money.aspx#/#TradeCurrency_tab 
- it doesn't work, and just loads the www.roblox.com screen.

Could anyone help clarify this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, I guess it doesn't throw an exception?

Comment: Does it show the exactly the same roblox.com page? I just opened the second link on my browser and I was redirected to the login, so the same is probably happening with your code

Comment: Oh - it doesn't throw an exception.  And the code that it retrieves is indeed the login page.  Does anyone know how to "sign in" with java so that I can view this page?

Comment: Perhaps roblox.com use a sessionid stored in a cookie that you only get on the start page and have to use on the other pages. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with this?  I'm not too good with programming vocab.

Comment: A cookie is a file where website can store some information on the client computer. For example a session id. I think roblox.com create a session id when you call the home page. When you call the secound page the server redirect you to the home page because you do not submit a valid session id.

Comment: @JackTools.Net how would I create a session id in java?

Comment: The server creates the session id for you. You have to pass it from one url connection to the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the URL and the use of # I suspect this page is using javascript to dynamically create pages.

You can use something like http://seleniumhq.org/ to emulate a web-browser (including cookies) and this is a far more reliable approach for any kind of dynamic web content.

```
    // The Firefox driver supports javascript 
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // Go to the roblox page
    driver.get("http://www.roblox.com");

    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

Of course, there are many better ways to access elements of a page via Selenium's WebDriver API:  http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html

Download the JAR and all the deps in one file: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.27.0.jar

And note, you can navigate to other pages via code:  http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html -

```
     WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click Here Or Whatever"));
     link.click();
```

then

```
     System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

will get the page text on the next page.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement selenium.  Is there no other way of retrieving the html of this webpage?

Comment: see this for an example of using selentium in java code: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

You are getting different content in java than you see in the browser because the server adds the following header to the response:

```
Location=https://www.roblox.com/Login/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMy%2fMoney.aspx
```

You should get headers' values from URLConnection and redirect manually if the 'Location' header is present. As far as I know even if you used HttpConnection you won't be redirect automatically to 'https'

EDITED:

You could do it with smth like this (I removed other code, like exception handling just to focus on redirection, so don't take it as proper 'coding' example):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    printPage("http://www.roblox.com/My/Money.aspx#/#TradeCurrency_tab");       
}

public static void printPage(String address) throws Exception {     
    String line = null;
    System.out.println("connecting to:" + address);
    URL url = new URL(address);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    String redirectAdress = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
    if (redirectAdress != null) {
        printPage(redirectAdress);
    } else {
        InputStream is = url.openStream(); 
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
        while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the output from my program looked like this:            <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://www.roblox.com/Login/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMy%2fMoney.aspx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>  Then I tried copying the "https://www.robl ..." link into my program, and it spit out the login page.  Could anyone help with this?

Comment: I edited my post to add an example of how you could handle the redirect. So if 'Location' header is present, then it doesn't print to the output but follows that location.